# How do I git blame without seeing merges

Tags: git, blame

If I've got a file whose history is like this:

```
----A----B
     \    \
      C----D----E
```

and I do a blame from E then I'd like to see what changed in revisions B & C, but I don't really care about D, since that was a merge.

Is there a way I can do this? I guess I'm looking for some kind of --no-merges option to git blame, but I'm not seeing one in the [manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html).

Comment: Next time just try. git blame --no-merges -- works because --no-merges is passed directly to git-rev-list

Comment: Perhaps change to "without seeing trivial merges".

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *do* care about D. Consider this case:

```
in commit B:
2) banana
3) coconut
4) domino     // conflicts with C

in commit C:
2) banana
3) coconut
4) elephant   // conflicts with B
```

In commit D, we resolve the conflict:

```
in commit D:
2) banana
3) coconut
4) domino-elephant
```

Notice that in D, a line appears which didn't appear in either B or C. If you ignore merges, you would never see that, and you'd never be able to tell where line 4 came from, which is bad.

Comment: ah, ok, good point. But is there an easy way I can step past that If I want to? Or do I need to go and re-blame the whole file with that merge as the top? in which case how do I get past the merge & know which side of the tree I've gone down?

Comment: "Stepping past" a commit is just starting from an earlier point, really -- so just `git blame` and start from the merge commit rather than HEAD. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Supposed the original question was "I would like to avoid seeing trivial merges". Merges without conflicts do not tell me which developer to talk to.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. I believe the answer is to pass `--no-merges`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `git log -L start,end:filename` which shows (by default, the complete) history of the line or lines numbered between `start` and `end` in `filename`. You can also use `git log -L /regex/,/regexend/:filename` to identify lines by a regex instead of by line numbers. By its nature you will probably get different results than with `git blame` in many cases, but I was able to find the "real" (i.e. non-merge) change more conveniently than with `git blame`.